# How to import to a column of DataFrame a text, skipping the colspec (PYTHON)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text of the form:

```
adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421  2 4321 12 
adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421  2 4321 12
```

I want to put it inside col1 of a dataframe like:

```
                      col1                           
0 adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421  2 4321 12       
1 adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12         
2 adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
3 adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
4 adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
5 adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421  2 4321 12
```

Im using: pd.read_fwd("text.txt", header = None) but is not working since it returns me a dataframe with 7 columns.

How could I put all the text in a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **colspecs** parameter to achieve this.

colspecs takes list of pairs (tuples) giving the extents of the fixed-width fields of each line as half-open intervals (i.e., [from, to[ ). 
In this case i've taken the interval as 100(any higher no.)

```
colspecs = [(0,100)] 
df = pd.read_fwf("text.txt",colspecs=colspecs,names = ['Col1'])
```

Output:

```
                                            Col1
0  adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421  2 4321 12
1  adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
2  adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
3  adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
4  adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
5  adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421  2 4321 12
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
temp = StringIO("""  
adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421  2 4321 12 
adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421  2 4321 12
""")


df = pd.read_csv(temp, sep='|', names=['col1'])
```

**Output**

```
                                             col1
0  adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421  2 4321 12 
1   adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
2   adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
3   adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
4   adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421    4321 12
5   adadaff afdfsfs   fdsfsfsd   32421  2 4321 12
```

Comment: @jezrael thanks...it was an old stuff which i used..never really bothered to change..ya in this case it doesn't makes a diff